# How to extract only specified part of string in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a situation where one of my column is bike name that contains value like 
RoyalEnfeild Classic 350
I want only the company name i.e RoyalEnfeild  to be replace in that column.

so that all the values of that particular column should be changed with the new string

For example:

old table is like --

```
Bike Name 
RoyalEnfeild Classic 350
RoyalEnfeild Classic 350
KTM dUKE 390
```

NEW Table

```
Bike Name
RoyalEnfeild
RoyalEnfeild 
KTM
```

I am new to python can anyone help me with the answer ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that only the very first word will be the company name and the rest of it is not?

Comment: You need some sort of pattern to match. If you have a pattern you can just use python regex.

Comment: @Endyd yes it is fixed that first word is company name

Answer (score 0):

For this example try:

```
 df['Bike Name'].str.extract('(\w+)')
```

Output:

```
              0
0  RoyalEnfeild
1  RoyalEnfeild
2           KTM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string slicing in case it's a string.Or if it's an array then you can access that element and assingn it to the whatever string you want to assign.
[arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)[string slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)